# How is CALayer.shadowOffset set from CGSize?

Tags: swift, cgsize

If I do `view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)` what exactly does the numbers -1 for width, and 1 for height mean? How is the shadow determined from the CGSize passed? I found the documentation, but it's not very useful

Comment: It means one point difference from the current frame. Negative/positive on width should be used to set either it's the shadow needs a translation to left/right. Negative/positive on height should be used to set either it's the shadow needs a translation to top/bottom. I'd suggest to create 4 views, apply a shadow on them of "w:0,h:4", "w:0,h-4", "w:4,h:0", "w-4:h:0" to illustrate it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider `width` and `height` as `x` and `y`. And you should be aware in iOS coordinates start from **top left**. 
`CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)` means that the shadow will move 1 point to the left on x-axis and 1 point up on y-axis.